# Use 2 different login methods: JWT token and Google sign-in in one app

Tags: android, rest, authentication, jwt, google-signin

I have an application that is on the client side: android app, and on the server side: flask based rest api, login with JWT token.

For better security, I want to combine login with Google as well.

The problem is:
The naive solution, is on the client side: 
I need to "SPLIT" the login code for the 2 cases - That's not so bad, 
But later on for each request to the server - I need to check if I have jwt token, or google user data, and send the correct call.

Then on the server side as well - I need to "SPLIT" my code at every part of the Api to check weather it had jwt token or Google user. 
This naive solution seems ugly to me, and i'm asking if there is a better approach to this problem.

My friend suggested me to drop the jwt connecting and use only google, but from the user's side, I think it's better to have the 2 as options and to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward answer: Why don't you give the user a JWT token after they've logged in with Google? How we usually do this is: Login on client -> Send Google token -> Server verifies and sends JWT token -> User uses JWT Token and server uses Google token for updating the user information like the profile image or name.

Comment: I don't want a connection between the JWT and the Google token. 
I want to allow users that don't want to login with google use normal login with username and password, 
and for users who wants to login with google to use it.

I understand from your answer that you suggest to merge the 2 solutions, first login with google, and then use the jwt token. But if a user don't want to use google ?

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way. Otherwise you'll need active authentication between the user and Google.

Comment: I've read more about it. 
I understand that for Login, the user can use Google sign-in or normal sign-in, in the same way they'll get JWT token as a response and work with it. So there is not a need to change every place on the app. I'm trying to figure out a good way to do it in the Flask server that is currently configured to JWT only

Comment: It should not be to much effort. But take a look at the social medias policies first. They usually have rules about how often you should update the social media image of the user etcetera.